# unable install svn plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

i want install svn plugin with eclipse. and i found this site for instruction

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php

and i give following download link on my "Help-- Install New Software" option

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.0/update-site-1.0.1/

but when i try to download the plugin eclipse give me following error

[image]

i dont why ?

Comment: i believe you forgot to attach the error.. :)

Comment: no. actually this image contain my error. and no any other error i can see on eclipse board.

Comment: "this image" -- where is the image?

Comment: i dont know why you cant see image. but in my question i post a screen shot of my problem

Comment: But it is not visible to me... :( is it a link to an image?

Comment: no i just upload a screen shot of image from my desktop.
no its not a image link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from your tutorial:

```
On the 'Add Repository' form enter the URL to the Subversive update site. 
The proper URL can be found on http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php. 
Also the update-site for Subversive integration plug-ins can be added in 
the same way.
```

The link provided above is **not** the update-repository, its just an information page where you can find the latest repository URL.

Try this one:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.0/update-site-1.0.1/
```

Hope this helpes, have Fun!

Comment: sorry for mistake but i was using this link http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.0/update-site-1.0.1/

and has same error.